# Is it possible to have nested union types in TypeGraphQL?

Tags: typescript, graphql, typegraphql

Say I have two union types like so:

```
import { createUnionType } from "type-graphql";

const InstagramUnion = createUnionType({
  name: "Instagram",
  types: () => [InstagramWidget1, InstagramWidget2] as const,
});

const SpotifyUnion = createUnionType({
  name: "Spotify",
  types: () => [SpotifyWidget1, SpotifyWidget2] as const,
});
```

Currently, I'm unable to create a union of the above two unions:

```
const WidgetUnion = createUnionType({
  name: "Widget",
  types: () => [SpotifyUnion, InstagramUnion] as const, // error, not assignable
});
```

Is it possible to do this? Basically, I need a resultant union that looks like this:

```
InstagramWidget1 | InstagramWidget2 | SpotifyWidget1 | SpotifyWidget2
```

Comment: Did you get a solution? If so, please do share here.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible in any GraphQL implementation as it's not supported by GraphQL spec.